# Google calendar API error under Python3

Tags: python, python-3.4, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm working with the *google-api-python-client* library with the following setup:

- Python3.4.3 in a virtual environment (using pip8.1.1)

I'm getting error from the following code: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'file'**

```
store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
```

The code is from the [Google Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) example and runs fine under Python 2.7.10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens, if you are in a python console, and do the following:
`import oauth2client; dir(oauth2client)` ?

Comment: I get the following: `['GOOGLE_AUTH_URI',
 'GOOGLE_DEVICE_URI',
 'GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI',
 'GOOGLE_TOKEN_INFO_URI',
 'GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__version__']`

Comment: What is your `oauth2client.__version__`?
See what happens if you add `import oauth2client.file` after `import oauth2client` in the quickstart.py code. OR, horribly hacky, `from oauth2client import file as oauth2client_file; oauth2client.file = oauth2client_file`.

Comment: My `oath2client.__version__` is '1.4.12'

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot, though! At least I have a _real_ issue and I'm not missing something silly. I think I'll try a fresh setup on a different computer and see if the problem is repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by rewriting the import statement: 
`from oauth2client.file import Storage`
Not sure why this works, but it does.